# Is it possible to access the camera of a handset from an application in android?

Tags: android, camera

I require to know if it is possible to open the camera of a handset from an Android application and click a picture to save it?  If so, what classes do I use?  Please give me a rough idea on how I can go about it.

Answer (score 2):

A basic and effective tutorial is present in android development website. [check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)